# C++ primer 5th Ed: The Word Transformation Program

Tags: c++

On chapter 11 from C++ Primer 5 Edition, the title "The Word Transformation Program" it has a function called `word_transform()` which is defined this way:

```
void word_transform(ifstream &map_file, ifstream &input)
{
    auto trans_map = buildMap(map_file); // store the transformations
    string text; // hold each line from the input
    while (getline(input, text)) { // read a line of input
        istringstream stream(text); // read each word
        string word;
        bool firstword = true; // controls whether a space is
        printed
            while (stream >> word) {
                if (firstword)
                    firstword = false;
                else
                    cout << " "; // print a space between words
                                 // transform returns its first argument or its transformation
                cout << transform(word, trans_map); // print the output
            }
        cout << endl; // done with this line of input
    }
}
```

- What I see if I am not wrong that the Boolean object `firstword` is redundant here and there's no need to check for a space and instead simply after calling `transform_word` which returns either a transformed text or original one then print it and simply print a space after it:

  ```
  void word_transform(ifstream &map_file, ifstream &input)
  {
      auto trans_map = buildMap(map_file); // store the transformations
      string text; // hold each line from the input
      while (getline(input, text)) { // read a line of input
          istringstream stream(text); // read each word
          string word;

          while (stream >> word)
              cout << transform(word, trans_map) << " ";
          cout << endl; // done with this line of input
      }
  }
  ```
- As you can see the function works fine. Please help whether I am correct or use the book's function.

Comment: You add a trailing space

Comment: @StoryTeller: Sorry. I didn't understand.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Thank you! I got it now.

Comment: @StoryTeller: In the function: There's no closing the files so should I close them? `input.close()...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, your way prints all the `transform(word, trans_map)` separated by spaces.  But you also print a redundant space at the end, which may or may not be of concern.

Comment: You know I always try to understand everything especially I'm learning on my own.

Comment: That's the best way.

Comment: Ok. One last thing this program doesn't close  files. Should I call close them. `input.close()` When I am done reading them?

Comment: No, the destructor for `std::ifstream` closes (calls `close()`) the file.

Comment: so it is not safe calling `close` explicitly?

Comment: Unless you really know what your doing in special use-cases, you don't ever call `close()` directly.